# How to fill a field with pre-defined options in the admin page

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new to Django and to learn it I'm trying to create a news-like site, where the news-posts are written in the admin page. To achieve this I created a model called Post, and, among other things, I want it to store the post genre. Therefore I made a variable called `genre` which equals `models.CharField()` method. The problem with this approach is that in the admin page I have to write the post genre every time, when instead I'd like to choose the genre from a set of pre-defined genres. How can I achieve this functionality in the admin page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a tuple of choices to your field and it will show up as a select widget in the admin.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    GENRE_CHOICES = (
        ('movie', 'Movie'),
        ('music', 'Music'),
    )
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=GENRE_CHOICES)
```